# Added Javascript property accessible but not visible

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

So I'm trying to add a property to an object that holds the object's name.  This will be used inside html name attributes etc.

```
setClientSideOpeningHours: =>
    newOpeningHours = {}
    existingOpeningHours = _.extend {}, @.get("opening_hours")
     _.each _.keys(existingOpeningHours), (item) ->
        newOpeningHours[item] = existingOpeningHours[item]
        newOpeningHours[item]["day"] = item
    console.log "openingHours.friday", newOpeningHours.friday,
                "openingHours.friday.day", newOpeningHours.friday.day
    @.set "clientside_opening_hours", newOpeningHours
```

In Chrome, this is printed to the console:

> openingHours.friday 
>   openingHours.friday: Object { is_closed: "true", **proto**: Object } 
>   openingHours.friday.day: friday

Later, outside of the model, when I call @.model.toJSON() or @.model.attributes, the day property is completely absent.  What is going on here?

EDIT: Got it working with $.extend(true,...)

```
setClientSideOpeningHours: =>
    newOpeningHours = {}
    existingOpeningHours = $.extend true, {}, @.get("opening_hours")
    _.each .keys(existingOpeningHourshours), (item) =>
        newOpeningHours[item] = $.extend true, {}, existingOpeningHours[item]
        newOpeningHours[item].day = item
    @.set "clientside_opening_hours", newOpeningHours
```

Comment: `_.extend` doesn't do a deep copy, nor does `=`. You could be sharing references that you're not expecting to. Can you produce a functional demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/?

Comment: Looks like I got $.extend and _.extend confused.

Comment: `$.extend` only does deep copies if you tell it to.